# Не работают inline кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Совсем недавно начал изучать Python и решил написать телеграм бота. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Кнопки "Да" и "Нет" работают, но кнопки  "Давай" и "Нет" почему то абсолютно не реагируют на нажатия. Почему такое может быть?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("мой токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['/start'])
def welcome(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да",callback_data="yes")
    item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет",callback_data="no")
    markup.add(item5, item6)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Хорошее настроение сегодня?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "yes":
            markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Давай",callback_data="ye")
            item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет",callback_data="ne")
            markup2.add(item7, item8)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Это хорошо. Давай дружить?', reply_markup=markup2)
        if call.data == "no":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text = "Это грустно(")

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "ye":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text = "Теперь мы друзья!")
        if call.data == "ne":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text = "Ты меня расстраиваешь(")
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не очень шарю в телеботе, но точно вижу что у вас два колбек хендлера с одинаковым условием/фильтром, поэтому срабатывает только один, который был обьявлен раньше.

Вам нужно поменять в скобках для колбек хендлеров ваши `func=lambda call:True` на `func=lambda c: c.data == 'yes' or c.data == 'no'`
И почти то же самое провернуть со вторым колбеком.
`func=lambda c: c.data == 'ye' or c.data == 'ne'`

Правда я рекомендую в колбекдата отправить не простое yes-no, а к примеру вот так:

```py
item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data="asq:yes")
item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data="asq:no")
# и потом в колбек хендлере который должен ловить эти кнопки будет следующее
func=lambda c: c.data.split(":")[0] == 'asq'
```

Ну и просто для примера здесь есть разные способы задать условие для колбек хендлеров. [ссылка тут](https://github.com/coder2020official/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/asynchronous_telebot/CallbackData_example.py)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я переискал весь интернет, прочитал кучу информации, но так и ничего не нашел, а оказывается это так легко решается. Еще вопрос, получается так нужно писать всегда, когда inline кнопок больше 1?

Comment: @HABAROW Да, до тех пор пока в боте есть на что-то на что реагируют колбек хендлеры. Да и вообще пустые колбек хендлеры это странно.